# vbs script upload only the file name without inside data

Tags: file-upload, vbscript, upload, ftp, filezilla

The problem of this script is that it shows an **unknown error Message** while running the script.

I called the function by echo method in my ftp which is "filezilla".
every thing is working fine as it logs into the server check for the path, open channel for data writing. Still dont know where is the problem

```
Function FTPUpload(sSite, sUsername, sPassword, sLocalFile, sRemotePath)
  'This script is provided under the Creative Commons license located
  'at http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/2.5/ . It may not
  'be used for commercial purposes with out the expressed written consent
  'of NateRice.com

  Const OpenAsDefault = -2
  Const FailIfNotExist = 0
  Const ForReading = 1
  Const ForWriting = 2

  Set oFTPScriptFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set oFTPScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

  sRemotePath = Trim(sRemotePath)
  sLocalFile = Trim(sLocalFile)

  '----------Path Checks---------
  'Here we willcheck the path, if it contains
  'spaces then we need to add quotes to ensure
  'it parses correctly.
  If InStr(sRemotePath, " ") > 0 Then
    If Left(sRemotePath, 1) <> """" And Right(sRemotePath, 1) <> """" Then
      sRemotePath = """" & sRemotePath & """"
    End If
  End If

  If InStr(sLocalFile, " ") > 0 Then
    If Left(sLocalFile, 1) <> """" And Right(sLocalFile, 1) <> """" Then
      sLocalFile = """" & sLocalFile & """"
    End If
  End If

  'Check to ensure that a remote path was
  'passed. If it's blank then pass a "\"
  If Len(sRemotePath) = 0 Then
    'Please note that no premptive checking of the
    'remote path is done. If it does not exist for some
    'reason. Unexpected results may occur.
    sRemotePath = "\"
  End If

  'Check the local path and file to ensure
  'that either the a file that exists was
  'passed or a wildcard was passed.
  If InStr(sLocalFile, "*") Then
    If InStr(sLocalFile, " ") Then
      FTPUpload = "Error: Wildcard uploads do not work if the path contains a " & _
      "space." & vbCRLF
      FTPUpload = FTPUpload & "This is a limitation of the Microsoft FTP client."
      Exit Function
    End If
  ElseIf Len(sLocalFile) = 0 Or Not oFTPScriptFSO.FileExists(sLocalFile) Then
    'nothing to upload
    FTPUpload = "Error: File Not Found."
    Exit Function
  End If
  '--------END Path Checks---------

  'build input file for ftp command
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "USER " & sUsername & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & sPassword & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "cd " & sRemotePath & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "binary" & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "prompt n" & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "put " & sLocalFile & vbCRLF
  sFTPScript = sFTPScript & "quit" & vbCRLF & "quit" & vbCRLF & "quit" & vbCRLF


  sFTPTemp = oFTPScriptShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%TEMP%")
  sFTPTempFile = sFTPTemp & "\" & oFTPScriptFSO.GetTempName
  sFTPResults = sFTPTemp & "\" & oFTPScriptFSO.GetTempName

  'Write the input file for the ftp command
  'to a temporary file.
  Set fFTPScript = oFTPScriptFSO.CreateTextFile(sFTPTempFile, True)
  fFTPScript.WriteLine(sFTPScript)
  fFTPScript.Close
  Set fFTPScript = Nothing  

  oFTPScriptShell.Run "%comspec% /c FTP -n -s:" & sFTPTempFile & " " & sSite & _
  " > " & sFTPResults, 0, TRUE

  Wscript.Sleep 1000

  'Check results of transfer.
  Set fFTPResults = oFTPScriptFSO.OpenTextFile(sFTPResults, ForReading, _
  FailIfNotExist, OpenAsDefault)
  sResults = fFTPResults.ReadAll
  fFTPResults.Close

  oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile(sFTPTempFile)
  oFTPScriptFSO.DeleteFile (sFTPResults)

  If InStr(sResults, "226 Transfer complete.") > 0 Then
    FTPUpload = True
  ElseIf InStr(sResults, "File not found") > 0 Then
    FTPUpload = "Error: File Not Found"
  ElseIf InStr(sResults, "cannot log in.") > 0 Then
    FTPUpload = "Error: Login Failed."
  Else
    FTPUpload = "Error: Unknown."
  End If

  Set oFTPScriptFSO = Nothing
  Set oFTPScriptShell = Nothing
  WScript.Echo "Process Completed (" & Now & ")"
End Function
```